# Make imageview appear above Gallery

Tags: android, layout, view, gallery, z-index

I have a Gallery widget and 2 imageviews, one on the left of the screen and one on the right. I want the imageview and gallery to stay on the same line, but if there is an overlap, the imageview's z-index should be higher then the gallery's.

The problem is the imageview appears underneath the gallery item. I've had a look in the android doc, but can't find the solution. My XML file is below (For some reason, the opening Root relative layout's opening and closing tag isn't showing up):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greenarrow_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green_arrow_right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>  

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greenarrow_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green_arrow_left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>  
<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spacing="3dip"         
/>

  <!-- more elements here -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last child of the `RelativeLayout` will be on top. If your layout is as depicted above, that means the `Gallery` will be on top of the second `ImageView`. Change your XML and the `RelativeLayout` rules to make the second `ImageView` appear after the `Gallery` in the XML.

Comment: Excellent, that solved it. Does the documentation mention this behaviour? I just checked and it mentions that when items depend on others, make sure the others appear first.

Comment: do elements of Gallery have something like z-index which can be changed or their z-index is fixed during populating of gallery view?

Comment: @Ewoks: "do elements of Gallery have something like z-index" -- not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `ViewParent.BringChildToFront(myImageView)` ?